# Comando para descrever os dados de uma tabela

Tags: r, dplyr

Olá,

Estou com uma base de dados e gostaria de saber quais os nomes dos campos através de um comando no R. Qual a melhor forma de proceder? Tentei utilizar describe() porém sem sucesso.

Comment: Se o conjunto de dados chama `df`, faça `names(df)`.

Comment: @MarcusNunes Ou `str(df)`.

Answer (score 5):

O `r-base` oferece as opções de:

1. `names()`: para conhecer os nomes das variáveis que estão no [data.frame](/questions/tagged/data.frame).
2. `str()`: para conhecer a estrutura do objeto em questão. No caso no `data.frame`, isso significa conhecer a quantidade de variáveis que ele tem, o número de observações e o nome, tipo e alguns valores de cada variável.

O `data.frame` usado nos exemplos (`sleep`) já vem no `R` (pacote `datasets`).

```
names(sleep)
[1] "extra" "group" "ID" 

str(sleep)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ extra: num  0.7 -1.6 -0.2 -1.2 -0.1 3.4 3.7 0.8 0 2 ...
 $ group: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ID   : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

O [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) oferece uma opção mais elegante ao `str()`: `glimpse()`.

```
dplyr::glimpse(sleep)
Observations: 20
Variables: 3
$ extra <dbl> 0.7, -1.6, -0.2, -1.2, -0.1, 3.4, 3.7, 0.8, 0.0, 2.0, ...
$ group <fct> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ...
$ ID    <fct> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,...
```